# How to undo "sudo -s" in OSX terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, root

I ran `sudo -s` in the OSX terminal and now it is defaulted to running as root.

Is there a way to undo this?

Answer (score 2):

On Unix Type operating systems, all you have to do is type in the `exit` command this should exit root and return to the user you were currently running under before entering the command.

You can also hit `Command+D` and that should return you to the user you were running as before the command as well.

Comment: I get the following output after entering `exit`:

`logout
    Saving session...
    ...copying shared history...
    ...saving history...truncating history files...
    ...completed.
    
    [Process completed]`

But after reopening the Terminal I'm still running as root.